# Where does visual studio setup project get the primary output file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, setup-project

I am trying to create a setup project for my C#-application in VS 2010. I am using an post built event during the creation of the c#-application. This event appends data to the binary of the application, because i need this data later.

The Problem is, that the file in the output-folder contains this appended data but the installed file of the setupproject doesnt contains it. My Question now is, where does VS get the output file for the setup project, so I can append the data to this file?

Comment: You ought to consider switching to a different technology for building your installer, given that setup projects no longer exist in VS 2012.

Comment: Ouuuw... that's dopey. I like the easy way to use the setup project in VS2010. Unless I have to use .net 4.5 I will uphold VS2010, the Design of 2012 has been unsuccessful.

Comment: Note that there is now an extension to add setup projects back into VS as of VS2013: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d

Comment: Separate download from MS allows to re-add setup projects to VS2017 and VS2019 (just posting to let anyone bumping into this ancient post know)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try adding "File" instead of "Project output" to your setup project.

Or you can just modify your output in /obj/release (or obj/debug) folder instead modifying it in output folder. (if you look on primary output properties - you will see that it uses files from obj... folder and not from output folder)

Comment: That's hard to comprehend why there are two files. Thank you. It works fine :)

Comment: yep good. But makes you mess around with the project resetting all the dependencies on the project output. Annoying but works.